# XML-parser error: no element found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a asp.net application which is located on a server.
It was working but then I added a whole bunch of stuff and now I get:

XML-parser error: no element found
Address: http://www.dtm.se/payex/Default.aspx
Row 1, Column 1:

(I have translated this error message from Swedish so it might not be 100% accurate)

The error occurs in Firefox when I upload the code to "my" site.
In IE 8 and Google Chrome I get blank pages.
When I compile it it locally it runs without issues.

I have set up IIS (7.0) on my machine and it works there to.

I have checked the files on the server just in case there was something wrong with the upload but the code was there.

I also have tried to remove the code I have added to see if I can get it to work again.
But no. Of course I am not 100% sure I got everything back to the way it was.

It doesn't matter which file I am trying to load all of them get this error message.

Hmm, when I write this I get the feeling it might be something wrong with the way the asp.net application i set up on the server.
But since it worked from the beginning...

There is a lot of code so I don't know really what to upload here but maybe someone recognize this error message and knows what it is or maybe point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was using MySql and when I added the reference to the connector it added a line in web.config, but it didn't add the dll in the bin folder.
So when the server tried to access the file it thru this error.
So I added the file manually to the bin folder and, tada, it started working.

I disinctly remember VisualStudio adding the files when I choose add reference.
But maybe I had it mixed up with something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your Default.aspx page appears to have the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears that Firefox assumes this to be an XML document (with no data) and throws an error in this case (Maybe something to do with the DOCTYPE). It is also possible that .NET generates a response type of "application/xml" in this case, though I cannot confirm that. IE 7 shows a blank page as expected.

What you should look into is why your page is giving blank output. Are you sure that the site is configured to run with the correct version of ASP.NET?