# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost:8000/web.config Line Number 1, Column 1

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, iis, iis-7

I'm a newbie to WCF and IIS, and when I try to host a web service in IIS and open it in the browser it shows me the above XML Parsing error. I've tried all the points mentioned in related posts, but it doesnt seem to work. Is there any solution that I might have missed out?

EDIT: i followed all the steps exactly as mentioned here. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVPXLF-g4Ws ... But , i still get the same XML parsing error when i try to host the service in IIS. If possible, can anyone try following that video and tell me if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be many things that will cause this. If you are using some 3rd party libraries like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823542/xml-parser-error-no-element-found), check bin folder. Another suggestion is to place Global.asax in root of app and try to catch more detailed exception in Application_Error.

Comment: I checked the bin folder and placed the Global.asax file too. Do you think I'm making a fundamental mistake somewhere?

Comment: Maybe there is no handler for .svc http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0db19bc8-2bc4-4306-a124-65b80849c0e3?

Answer (score 1):

In my service's web.config file, I ended up setting the endpoint's "Address" attribute to an empty string.  Fixed it, right on refresh.

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="AgentServiceBinding"
          contract="HBW.Services.Agent.IAgentService">
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your web.config file is blank. If so, try using the integrated Visual Studio Debug/Export to auto-generate a web.config file.

Comment: Is it the start new instance in the Debug mode you are talking of?

Comment: Try running your site by pressing F5.

Comment: I did that before. I have the web.config file and its not empty. When i launch the browser it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Here's the link to my web.config file : http://pastebin.com/tUHLGSx2 Should I modify this by any chance, or is this one fine?

Comment: The error is telling me that you have an empty web.config file. I.E., it can't find a beginning node. Firefox gives a similar message when you give it an empty file with a .XML extension. Unless this file is somewhere other than your root directory, I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and restarting my website on IIS solved my problem. If other options fails, try this one.