# IIS 7.5 500 24 50 41 error on log

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

This is my web config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="vmpcon" connectionString="data source=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;User ID=sa;Password=XXXXX; Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>

      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
    </system.web>



</configuration>
```

When I access that website from chrome and IE, I got **empty page**, when I access it from FireFox I got

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://XXXXX:portNumber/index.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

when I access the log, I found this:

```
2014-09-24 13:18:41 IPXXXXX GET /index.aspx - Port - IPXXXXX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/37.0.2062.120+Safari/537.36 500 24 50 41
```

The static content is already enabled, I tried almost all the solutions I found in internet but nothing works,

help please

**Integrated , .NET 4.5**

**IIS 7.5**

**Windows server 2008 r2**

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost:8000/web.config Line Number 1, Column 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193297/xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-location-http-localhost8000-web-config-l)

Comment: @Reniuz it is not duplicated my friend, please look at that question, the answer there was because of using a third party library, I am not using any third party library, please please don't make this question as a duplicated because it is not

Comment: No, there was 2 suggestions. 1. Check 3rd party lib 2. place Global.asax in root of app and try to catch more detailed exception in Application_Error. P.s. please please write what you have and what you have done because we cant forecast this. You mentioned you tried ALMOST ALL so what was the solution you tired and failed?

Comment: Also have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404342/asp-net-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-line-number-1-column-1-error It says that Firefox shows this error when no html was received. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Reniuz I don't have Global.asax in myapp

Comment: @Reniuz any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Ok have you tried to look at firebug? Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404342/asp-net-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-line-number-1-column-1-error? Also can you share index.aspx content and code behind probably (Iam not web dev so keep in mind :))

Comment: @Reniuz I don't have `aspnet_regiis.exe`in my `Framework64/v4.0.30319` folder. and when looking at firebug, I got response length is zero. when I change to clasic, I got `404.17` error, pleae help if you can

Comment: @Reniuz finally I found the solution and I wrote my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstalling .net again and then running `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` which locates in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` solved the problem